# build Ajax Data section by calling a local function that returns parameters

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am having trouble figuring this simple thing out. Sorry I have tried all combinations of this and I cannot get it to work. Here is what I am trying to do

I have a javascrip function

```
  function getSelectedSearchCriteria() {
               var data = {};
               data.projname = "Test Project";
               return data;
}
```

my Ajax function is called as

```
$.ajax({
url:  "/Position/PositionList", 
type: "POST", 
dataType: "json",
data:getSelectedSearchCriteria

}
```

my controller method is defined as

```
 public ViewResult PositionList(string projname)
{
..
}
```

However the projname parameter is always a null. Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your javascript function is being invoked? The sample code you provide is missing a () after getSelectedSearchCriteria

```
data:getSelectedSearchCriteria
```

to

```
data:getSelectedSearchCriteria()
```

Comment: Good catch Evan. The reason I missed that is because i had another function
function getSelectedPosition() {
               return $('input[name=positions]:checked').val();
           }

And for that i had to call without the brackets.
$.ajax({
url: "/Position/Edit/",
data: { id: getSelectedPosition },
dataType: 'html',
type: "GET"
}